# Sign out identityserver4 with identityserver3 library in mvc client

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, identityserver4, identityserver3

I have a IdentityServer4 authentication server. I also have an ASP.NET MVC (.Net Framework 4.6) web client. I'm trying to sign out the user, using

```
Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut();
```

It is then redirected to the authentication server account/logout view saying -
 You are now logged out. Click here to return to the client application.

After clicking the logout redirect, I am redirected to my page where I can click sign-in again. After clicking sign-in, i am automatically signed-in. Seems that sign-out does not work. What am I missing? Thank you

updated:
Identity Server 4 logs below

> [02:41:07 Debug] IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultClaimsService Getting
>   claims for access token for client: dpcdwebclient
>
> [02:41:07 Debug] IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultClaimsService Getting
>   claims for access token for client: dpcdwebclient
>
> [02:41:07 Debug] IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint Token request
>   success.
>
> [02:41:07 Debug] IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint Token request
>   success.
>
> [02:41:10 Information]
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler
>   AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was successfully
>   authenticated.
>
> [02:41:10 Information]
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler
>   AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was successfully
>   authenticated.
>
> [02:41:10 Information]
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler
>   AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was successfully
>   authenticated.
>
> [02:41:10 Information]
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler
>   AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was successfully
>   authenticated.
>
> [02:41:10 Debug] IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter Request path
>   /connect/endsession matched to endpoint type Endsession
>
> [02:41:10 Debug] IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter Request path
>   /connect/endsession matched to endpoint type Endsession
>
> [02:41:10 Debug] IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter Endpoint
>   enabled: Endsession, successfully created handler:
>   IdentityServer4.Endpoints.EndSessionEndpoint
>
> [02:41:10 Debug] IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter Endpoint
>   enabled: Endsession, successfully created handler:
>   IdentityServer4.Endpoints.EndSessionEndpoint
>
> [02:41:10 Information]
>   IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware Invoking
>   IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.EndSessionEndpoint
>   for /connect/endsession
>
> [02:41:10 Information]
>   IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware Invoking
>   IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.EndSessionEndpoint
>   for /connect/endsession
>
> [02:41:10 Debug] IdentityServer4.Endpoints.EndSessionEndpoint
>   Processing signout request for cc5a2d8c-77d9-477d-8eed-48b8cb7cc8df
>
> [02:41:10 Debug] IdentityServer4.Endpoints.EndSessionEndpoint
>   Processing signout request for cc5a2d8c-77d9-477d-8eed-48b8cb7cc8df
>
> [02:41:10 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.EndSessionRequestValidator
>   Start end session request validation
>
> [02:41:10 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.EndSessionRequestValidator
>   Start end session request validation
>
> [02:41:10 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenValidator Start
>   identity token validation
>
> [02:41:10 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenValidator Start
>   identity token validation
>
> [02:41:10 Debug] IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.ClientStore
>   dpcdwebclient found in database: True
>
> [02:41:10 Debug] IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.ClientStore
>   dpcdwebclient found in database: True
>
> [02:41:10 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenValidator Client
>   found: dpcdwebclient / DPCD Web Client
>
> [02:41:10 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenValidator Client
>   found: dpcdwebclient / DPCD Web Client
>
> [02:41:10 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenValidator Calling
>   into custom token validator:
>   IdentityServer4.Validation.DefaultCustomTokenValidator
>
> [02:41:10 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenValidator Calling
>   into custom token validator:
>   IdentityServer4.Validation.DefaultCustomTokenValidator
>
> [02:41:10 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenValidator Token
>   validation success {   "ClientId": "dpcdwebclient",   "ClientName":
>   "DPCD Web Client",   "ValidateLifetime": false,   "Claims": {
>       "nbf": 1516560060,
>       "exp": 1516560360,
>       "iss": "http://localhost:9000",
>       "aud": "dpcdwebclient",
>       "nonce": "636521568596713051.ZGU2MmM3YzMtMjI5Yi00YmFlLThhMzUtOTBjM2U2NWIwZjhjZThmZmNkN2EtNmFlYS00NjZiLWExMWMtNjY3YjEzYmM4YzY5",
>       "iat": 1516560060,
>       "c_hash": "OOI3bdt6NUGB4bptfc9w_A",
>       "sid": "5caef14630a16f452d9b0bfe03906fe5",
>       "sub": "cc5a2d8c-77d9-477d-8eed-48b8cb7cc8df",
>       "auth_time": 1516559499,
>       "idp": "local",
>       "amr": "pwd"   } }
>
> [02:41:10 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenValidator Token
>   validation success {   "ClientId": "dpcdwebclient",   "ClientName":
>   "DPCD Web Client",   "ValidateLifetime": false,   "Claims": {
>       "nbf": 1516560060,
>       "exp": 1516560360,
>       "iss": "http://localhost:9000",
>       "aud": "dpcdwebclient",
>       "nonce": "636521568596713051.ZGU2MmM3YzMtMjI5Yi00YmFlLThhMzUtOTBjM2U2NWIwZjhjZThmZmNkN2EtNmFlYS00NjZiLWExMWMtNjY3YjEzYmM4YzY5",
>       "iat": 1516560060,
>       "c_hash": "OOI3bdt6NUGB4bptfc9w_A",
>       "sid": "5caef14630a16f452d9b0bfe03906fe5",
>       "sub": "cc5a2d8c-77d9-477d-8eed-48b8cb7cc8df",
>       "auth_time": 1516559499,
>       "idp": "local",
>       "amr": "pwd"   } }
>
> [02:41:10 Information]
>   IdentityServer4.Validation.EndSessionRequestValidator End session
>   request validation success {   "ClientId": "dpcdwebclient",
>   "ClientName": "DPCD Web Client",   "SubjectId":
>   "cc5a2d8c-77d9-477d-8eed-48b8cb7cc8df",   "PostLogOutUri":
>   "http://localhost:9002/signout-callback-oidc",   "Raw": {
>       "id_token_hint": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjdmMjM1MDRjNjc3NzkzM2I0MDU5ODU5ZDA4MTMzOGMyIiwidHlwIjoiSldUIn0.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.P7Zn6GVdSuUaFS55DGqjA2PlRYH0CLIHPI7AKtOnNYn24sTagOBlX57Fg_QVmCczLrkdIwh-Deok2bXjf3O5ZrYKWN3OFKqkDx0CfTN3zypxruiumWEdhqtK_13iinh2n1XLiV0OeUozOCMsDVI2hMTcnHQxsIGlQigETeoRaG6NlB5jGB5-3i7DCJycywPyWV-CcMLJkEiAunLbVXGOsdALQxZTYFsXlffQA4vRybAK6d5Ybc5139vjW68jV4Rbjm9ihhFv4edwALcEYPICBWLR0FxGLWd6XOH56rK7HCoiom4v8afgFimS4MhfyEIkuKu0md46XrBF2MYy3xtdOQ",
>       "x-client-SKU": "ID_NET",
>       "x-client-ver": "1.0.40306.1554"   } }
>
> [02:41:10 Information]
>   IdentityServer4.Validation.EndSessionRequestValidator End session
>   request validation success {   "ClientId": "dpcdwebclient",
>   "ClientName": "DPCD Web Client",   "SubjectId":
>   "cc5a2d8c-77d9-477d-8eed-48b8cb7cc8df",   "PostLogOutUri":
>   "http://localhost:9002/signout-callback-oidc",   "Raw": {
>       "id_token_hint": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjdmMjM1MDRjNjc3NzkzM2I0MDU5ODU5ZDA4MTMzOGMyIiwidHlwIjoiSldUIn0.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.P7Zn6GVdSuUaFS55DGqjA2PlRYH0CLIHPI7AKtOnNYn24sTagOBlX57Fg_QVmCczLrkdIwh-Deok2bXjf3O5ZrYKWN3OFKqkDx0CfTN3zypxruiumWEdhqtK_13iinh2n1XLiV0OeUozOCMsDVI2hMTcnHQxsIGlQigETeoRaG6NlB5jGB5-3i7DCJycywPyWV-CcMLJkEiAunLbVXGOsdALQxZTYFsXlffQA4vRybAK6d5Ybc5139vjW68jV4Rbjm9ihhFv4edwALcEYPICBWLR0FxGLWd6XOH56rK7HCoiom4v8afgFimS4MhfyEIkuKu0md46XrBF2MYy3xtdOQ",
>       "x-client-SKU": "ID_NET",
>       "x-client-ver": "1.0.40306.1554"   } }
>
> [02:41:10 Debug] IdentityServer4.Endpoints.EndSessionEndpoint Success
>   validating end session request from dpcdwebclient
>
> [02:41:10 Debug] IdentityServer4.Endpoints.EndSessionEndpoint Success
>   validating end session request from dpcdwebclient
>
> [02:41:10 Information]
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler
>   AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was successfully
>   authenticated.
>
> [02:41:10 Information]
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler
>   AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was successfully
>   authenticated.
>
> [02:41:10 Information]
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler
>   AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was successfully
>   authenticated.
>
> [02:41:10 Information]
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler
>   AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was successfully
>   authenticated.
>
> [02:41:12 Information]
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler
>   AuthenticationScheme: Identity.External signed out.
>
> [02:41:12 Information]
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler
>   AuthenticationScheme: Identity.External signed out.
>
> [02:41:12 Information]
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler
>   AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was successfully
>   authenticated.
>
> [02:41:12 Information]
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler
>   AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was successfully
>   authenticated.
>
> [02:41:12 Information]
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler
>   AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was successfully
>   authenticated.
>
> [02:41:12 Information]
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler
>   AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was successfully
>   authenticated.
>
> [02:41:12 Debug] IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter Request path
>   /connect/endsession/callback matched to endpoint type Endsession
>
> [02:41:12 Debug] IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter Request path
>   /connect/endsession/callback matched to endpoint type Endsession
>
> [02:41:12 Debug] IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter Endpoint
>   enabled: Endsession, successfully created handler:
>   IdentityServer4.Endpoints.EndSessionCallbackEndpoint
>
> [02:41:12 Debug] IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter Endpoint
>   enabled: Endsession, successfully created handler:
>   IdentityServer4.Endpoints.EndSessionCallbackEndpoint
>
> [02:41:12 Information]
>   IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware Invoking
>   IdentityServer endpoint:
>   IdentityServer4.Endpoints.EndSessionCallbackEndpoint for
>   /connect/endsession/callback
>
> [02:41:12 Information]
>   IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware Invoking
>   IdentityServer endpoint:
>   IdentityServer4.Endpoints.EndSessionCallbackEndpoint for
>   /connect/endsession/callback
>
> [02:41:12 Debug] IdentityServer4.Endpoints.EndSessionCallbackEndpoint
>   Processing signout callback request
>
> [02:41:12 Debug] IdentityServer4.Endpoints.EndSessionCallbackEndpoint
>   Processing signout callback request
>
> [02:41:12 Debug] IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.ClientStore
>   dpcdwebclient found in database: True
>
> [02:41:12 Debug] IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.ClientStore
>   dpcdwebclient found in database: True
>
> [02:41:12 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.EndSessionRequestValidator
>   No client front-channel logout URLs
>
> [02:41:12 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.EndSessionRequestValidator
>   No client front-channel logout URLs
>
> [02:41:12 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.EndSessionRequestValidator
>   No client back-channel logout URLs
>
> [02:41:12 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.EndSessionRequestValidator
>   No client back-channel logout URLs
>
> [02:41:12 Information]
>   IdentityServer4.Endpoints.EndSessionCallbackEndpoint Successful
>   signout callback.
>
> [02:41:12 Information]
>   IdentityServer4.Endpoints.EndSessionCallbackEndpoint Successful
>   signout callback.
>
> [02:41:12 Debug] IdentityServer4.Endpoints.EndSessionCallbackEndpoint
>   No client front-channel iframe urls
>
> [02:41:12 Debug] IdentityServer4.Endpoints.EndSessionCallbackEndpoint
>   No client front-channel iframe urls
>
> [02:41:12 Debug] IdentityServer4.Endpoints.EndSessionCallbackEndpoint
>   No client back-channel iframe urls
>
> [02:41:12 Debug] IdentityServer4.Endpoints.EndSessionCallbackEndpoint
>   No client back-channel iframe urls

ASP.NET MVC 5 (Identity Server 3) Logout code:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult SignOut()
    {
        Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut();
        return Redirect("/");
    }

    //signout-oidc redirect
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult LogoutCallback()
    {
        Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut("Cookies");
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

IDS4 Logout (from sample codes)

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Logout(LogoutInputModel model)
    {
        // build a model so the logged out page knows what to display
        var vm = await _account.BuildLoggedOutViewModelAsync(model.LogoutId);

        var user = HttpContext.User;
        if (user?.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true)
        {
            // delete local authentication cookie
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();

            // raise the logout event
            await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLogoutSuccessEvent(user.GetSubjectId(), user.GetDisplayName()));
        }

        // check if we need to trigger sign-out at an upstream identity provider
        if (vm.TriggerExternalSignout)
        {
            // build a return URL so the upstream provider will redirect back
            // to us after the user has logged out. this allows us to then
            // complete our single sign-out processing.
            string url = Url.Action("Logout", new { logoutId = vm.LogoutId });

            // this triggers a redirect to the external provider for sign-out
            return SignOut(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = url }, vm.ExternalAuthenticationScheme);
        }

        return View("LoggedOut", vm);
    }
```

Client Configuration:

```
new Client
            {
                ClientId = "dpcdwebclient",
                ClientName = "DPCD Web Client",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,
                Enabled = true,

                RequireConsent = false,

                ClientSecrets =
                {
                    new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                },

                RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:9002/signin-oidc" },
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:9002/signout-callback-oidc" },

                AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true,

                AllowedScopes =
                {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OfflineAccess,
                    "myapi"
                },

                AllowOfflineAccess = true
            },
```

Comment: If you can post full MVC signout method and IS4 Logout method I can compare with my working code. And are you using Core 1.5 or 2.0 on IS4 side? Regards

Comment: hi @ozgurozkanakdemirci, sure. I'm using Core 2.0 on IS4 side. I'll update my post with my full code.

Comment: One obvious difference is PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:9002/signout-callback-oidc" }, as i remember, you dont need to express sigout-callback-oidc

Comment: But, I think even if the user didn't click on the redirect url, the user will still be automatically signed-in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

1. In your client (the MVC app), in the startup, where configuring the `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions`, in the `Notifications` you should have:

   ```
   RedirectToIdentityProvider = n =>
               {
                   // if signing out, add the id_token_hint
                   if (n.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.LogoutRequest)
                   {
                       var idTokenHint = n.OwinContext.Authentication.User.FindFirst("id_token");

                       if (idTokenHint != null)
                       {
                           n.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = idTokenHint.Value;
                       }

                   }
                   return Task.FromResult(0);
               },
   ```
2. Then in your controllers - when you call the logout action (user clicks the logout button or whatever):

   ```
   public ActionResult Logout()
   {
       Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut();
       return Redirect("/");
   }
   ```
3. Then, when configuring your client on the IdentityServer side, the `PostLogoutRedirectUris` are up to you, but they are not the signout call back. This should be some page in your client (anonymous allowed), that says that the user is logged out or something like this (up to you). The important property is 
   `FrontChannelLogoutUri` which you should set to call this:

   ```
   public void SignoutCleanup(string sid)
   {
       var cp = (ClaimsPrincipal)User;
       var sidClaim = cp.FindFirst("sid");
       if (sidClaim != null && sidClaim.Value == sid)
       {
           Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut("Cookies");
       }
   }
   ```

You can also use `BackChannelLogoutUri` - depending on your clients, check [here](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/signout.html).

My guess is that your step 2 is fine, and you need to tweak the things around steps 1 and 3, but start from step 1. This is the step that says to IdentityServer to logout the user, by sending the ID token.

I hope that this helps.

Comment: hi, i can affirm that i got step 1 correctly since I am getting the success logout message of IDS4. What I do not understand is the BackChannelLogoutUri and FrontChannelLogoutUri since from the logs, I am getting:
[02:41:12 Debug] IdentityServer4.Endpoints.EndSessionCallbackEndpoint No client front-channel iframe urls

[02:41:12 Debug] IdentityServer4.Endpoints.EndSessionCallbackEndpoint No client back-channel iframe urls

I also tried step 3 before. But I can't seem to figure out where to get the sid. since i think i did not set the FrontChannelLogoutUri and BackChannelLogoutUri.

Comment: Try setting them to `http://localhost:9002/signout-callback-oidc` (according to your client configuration) the sid will come in there as in step 3

Comment: I'll try this and will get back to you. Thank you

Comment: i implemented the solution but i'm having null value for the cp.FindFirst("sid"). I tried forcing to remove the cookie but I am again automatically signed-in.

Comment: not only the sid is missing but all claims are not available inside the SignoutCleanup(). But, why does the client still recognizes the user logged in when calling any Actions with [Authorized] attribute?

Comment: Did it work? I saw you accepted the answer. About the claims - if the method is not behind authorize attribute, the user comes as a Windows Principal, and there are no claims in it.

Comment: yes, i was really missing the BackChannelLogoutUri setting. After that, I cleaned my code in the Login Method to remove existing data. Thanks!

Comment: @pau_learnstocode I'm running into the same issue.  I setup the backchannel uri on IdSvr4 and it hits that SignoutCleanup endpoint on the client, but the sid value is null.  I'm not seeing the identity server append a query string for it in the backchannel request.  I didn't see anything on the spec about configuring it for the sid value.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem - I have correctly defined the FrontChannelLogoutUri and the SignoutCleanup is getting called, but because the sidClaim cannot be extracted from the principal then the Owin signout is never performed.

Comment: What about the logout, and what is your result at the end?