# SSO In an old ASP.NET Web Forms website

Tags: webforms, forms-authentication, identityserver4

## **Context:**

The company I'm working for would like to achieve Single-Sign-On capabilities with a third party that uses the authorization code grant. Our product right now is built in .NET Framework 4.0 using Forms Authentication in a ASP.NET Web Forms application.

## **Question:**

Is there a way to achieve single sign-on with out the user having to sign in twice (once through forms auth, and another through the identity server)?
To elaborate, is there a way to have the identity server authenticate the user automatically after the user has successfully signed in through forms authentication?

Comment: I'm working on something like this right now as well.  I have a .NET (not core) MVC project that I'm trying to get to work with one of the flows (don't much care which right now) with IdentityServer4, which is on .NET core.  I tried to get the integration test project working, but it throws all kinds of exceptions (because this is on my local machine, I haven't put on SSL/https yet).

Comment: Found this, has a bit of a client config for the IdSvr4 host on the client:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48365146/sign-out-identityserver4-with-identityserver3-library-in-mvc-client

Comment: Found this conversation - the IdSvr3 clients are supposed to work with IdSvr4, so maybe most of my problems just have to do with not having TLS yet.  https://gitter.im/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4?at=57ebc764ca69aeb745b9a25b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to work around my issue by sending the users credentials on login to the identity server via ajax. I made a webapi controller that authenticates the user and sends back 'set-cookie' response headers for the idsrv auth cookie.

So now I'm signed into the original application, as well as the identity server all without the user having to manually sign in twice.
You just have to deal with a bunch of Cross-Origin-Requests stuff. Have to set "AllowCredentials" when setting up the CORS policy for the application to make the ajax request so that the 'set-cookie' headers actually apply.

```js
$.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://localhost:44304/api/login?username=testing&password=testing',
    crossDomain: true,
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    }
})
```

The api/login endpoint is defined in a Controller that just calls the `HttpContext.SignInAsync()` extension method.

Comment: There's probably a much safer way to pass the credentials rather than just having them straight up passed through query string =P.

Comment: It is anti-pattern. Hacker can brute force your ID Server.

Comment: Yes ad0ran, I am glad you found a way to talk to the server, sorry I couldn't help you more (I've worked in environments like that in the past myself).  IdentityServer really needs a way to talk to your client webapp backchannel to secure the connection.  If you had any way to do that, it's the most secure you can get because there's a three way conversation going on.  I would talk to your server admins and try to get trusted connections somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the IdSvr3 webforms client:  https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/Clients/WebFormsClient

From what I've read, IdentityServer3 clients (which are previous to .NET core) are supposed to work with IdentityServer4 (which has to run on .NET core) and will talk to IdentityServer4 successfully.

Comment: You just have to figure out which flow you want and add a client config on the IdentityServer host side for that, then reference to it from your webforms client.

Comment: Looks like that project follows an implicit grant flow with some initial OWIN setup. Unfortunately, I won't be able to migrate our product past .NET 4.0... And also, I'm not able to completely replace the current Form Authentication that we currently have. I was hoping there was a way, when i could maintain two authentication cookies, one from our original product which uses forms auth, and the 2nd one using identity server 4. It is possible, but the user would have to sign in twice, once through forms auth, and again through the identity server

Comment: There are several other clients as well, it is probably possible to use one of those and just put the methods in the proper place for webform setup.  Here's the one I am presently configuring for the MVC project I have:
https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/Clients/MVC%20OWIN%20Client%20(Hybrid)

Comment: Try just substituting the startup configuration and see what happens.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have the ability to implement any OWIN stuff as I'm constricted to using .NET 4.0. This means no startup configuration

Comment: Do you mean strictly .NET 4.0 or something later like 4.5.1?  I'm not sure what version Owin Katana was released, but that's pre .NET Core.

Comment: Strictly .NET 4.0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165181/discussion-between-jakej-and-ad0ran).

Comment: Basically, he can't open a listener because it's .NET 4.0 / he doesn't have access to Owin Katana.  If anyone has any ideas at this point, I'm out.